# First time writing a iOS app - How to ensure its backwards compatible?

Tags: ios, swift

TLDR; I am creating an app that uses both the photo & video camera. The user first scans a barcode, the value is parsed from the barcode, stored, and the name of the file (of the photo or video) is stored as BarcodeValue_TodaysDateTimeStamp.

How can I ensure that this app is backwards compatible with any iOS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can not make it available for all the ios versions because there are so many deprecated APIs as well architecture changes. Even if you do , It is going to be very hard. Best approach is to look for the ios version usage statistics, depending on that pick your minimum supporting version and work for there.

[image]

As you can see 93% of users use ios version 10+. Since you are working with images assets, after ios 8 [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos) was introduced. I suggest you use this framework and may be set your minimum ios version to 10.

Comment: Also, when you create a target in xcode you set the target version (say, 9.0).  Then the compiler will warn you if you use APIs that aren't available in that version (e.g. if they were introduced in 10.0)